# Restlet implementation with Guice

Tags: java, guice, restlet, persistent, guice-persist

Java development took a huge step forward with the introduction of [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation). My projects heavily depend on [Warp-persist](http://www.wideplay.com/guicewebextensions2) and its successor [GuicePersist](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GuicePersist) for persistency.

But there seems to be a mismatch between the use of Guice and Restlet.
It looks like its only possible to `@Inject` session and persistence factories from the servlet level.
For transaction handling i need Guice to create Restlet `ServerResources` which enable me to `@Inject` persistence stuff like [@Transactional](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Transactions) or [UnitOfWork](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Transactions).

- Is there any change for Guice on the roadmap of Restlet?
- Are there best practices for the use of Guice with Restlet?

Regards,

Roland Beuker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow Related already pointed me to the blog "[Restlet Guice extension considered ... unnecessary](http://tembrel.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/restlet-guice-extension-considered.html)"

And indeed there's already a Guice extension for Restlet; [Restlet Extensions => Guice](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/extensions/guice)